# Refund from wooCommerce with stripe

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am testing stripe with wooCommerce. When I refund an order in wooCommerce. Client got an email saying partially refund. I login into my stripe account, it didn't refund. I need to manually refund in stripe. I want to confirm that this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you refunded the order in Woocommerce, did you click the button to Refund via Stripe instead of Refund manually? If you clicked Refund via Stripe, and Stripe is connected properly, the order will refund in Stripe.

[image]

2. Have you setup a webhook endpoint in Stripe? For example, https://yourdomain.com/?wc-api=wc_stripeWoocommerce at https://dashboard.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Faccount%2Fwebhooks